# owlapi-contract maven dependency missing test package

Tags: owl-api

I'm trying the extend the TestBase class, but can't find the correct dependency for:

```
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.api.test.baseclasses.TestBase;
```

I'm not so familiair with Maven but added the following dependencies to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
  <artifactId>owlapi-contract</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
  <artifactId>owlapi-apibinding</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
  <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

I expected that the olwapi-contract dependency contained the test package. However, under my Maven dependencies I only see the following:

[image]

Am I missing a dependency, or is the owlapi-contract.jar incomplete?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, WoRedPanda. Can you add more detail about the error you see? E.g. what are the classes that you have unresolved dependencies for.

Comment: Kidney has provided a great answer. `TestBase` is a utility class for OWLAPI tests only, If you wish to extend it for your own tests, the easiest way is to check out the OWLAPI source code by cloning the repository and copying the code you wish to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing any dependency and the jar is complete.

The `org.semanticweb.owlapi.api.test.baseclasses.TestBase` class is in the `src/test/java` directory, so it's a test-related class and cannot be imported through a Maven dependency (basically, nothing in `src/test` is visible from a Maven dependency).

There are [ways](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html) to overcome this, but they involve changes to the imported library packaging(*owlapi-contracts* in this case), so you would have to checkout the OWLAPI code itself.